# How to determine event privacy in Facebook API v2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing a facebook app which needs to access a user's event invitations. I would like it to retrieve the location data of the event, but only if it is a PUBLIC event.

In v2.4, I can access detailed location data like country, latitude, and longitude, all of which I need for my purposes, which I cannot access in v2.3. However, it seems that I can access the event's privacy parameter in v2.3, but not v2.4.

When I attempt to access the privacy field in Facebook's Explorer tool with `GET/v2.4/{event-id}/?fields=privacy`, I receive this:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) privacy field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12
  }
}`

Furthermore, a var_dump of a graphEdge object created from `get('/me/events/not_replied')` does not show privacy information anywhere.

Is there really no way to determine an event's privacy in v2.4? Are there any known workarounds to determine whether an event is private or not without rolling back to v2.3 and losing detailed location data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they renamed it type.   When I request back ?fields=type I get  "type": "public".

hope this helps...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!